# Can't install Android emulator for IntelliJ on Windows, possibly due to path error

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I'm working on a Hello, World Android app using some slightly flaky company-specific tooling built on top of Gradle, along with IntelliJ IDEA. Doing this work on Windows 10, which may be relevant.

The thing about the company-internal tooling is that it automatically installs and provides an Android SDK via a custom Gradle plugin. So both IntelliJ and Gradle are using an Android SDK path provided by our internal tooling.

I'm running into an issue where I can't install an emulator via IntelliJ. Basically when I open the **Tools** ► **Android** ► **SDK Manager** menu item in IntelliJ, the **SDK Tools** sub-tab in the dialog box is grayed out (circled in the screenshot below). This is where I need to go to install the emulator.

Notice as well in the screenshot below that there is an error message relating to the path to the Android SDK, *The Android SDK location is too long*. For reference that path comes from our internal tooling, and on my Windows 10 machine, this path is a 204-character string to a valid location on my PC that begins with `C:\Users\<my username>\...`.

[image: Screenshot from IntelliJ showing issues in the SDK Tools dialog including 'The Android SDK location is too long']

In contrast, when I open the equivalent setting in Android Studio directly (note this is using a separate SDK, not the one obtained from the company tooling), I am able to go to the **SDK Tools** tab and install the emulator.

[image: Screengrab from Android Studio's Configure ► SDK Manager menu showing that emulator is installed]

Would appreciate your help solving this problem, which is ultimately to get the emulator installed. I suspect the *The Android SDK location is too long* error is related so help getting that fixed would also be appreciated.

My specific IntelliJ idea version is: **2019.2.1**, build #IU-192.6262.58.

Comment: Did you try moving it into `c:\android-sdk` and adjusting the location?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks. I know it's buried in the details, but I do not control the path of my Android SDK, at least not easily. It's automatically generated from the tooling. I might be able to shave off a few characters, say getting it down around 190 instead of 204, but I can't generate significant changes.

Comment: You can use `mklink` to create a junction to a location with the shorter path and specify it instead.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, it's a good suggestion, *but* the problem is I don't control the system that tells IntelliJ what the SDK path *is*. That itself is a black box. So while I can `mklink` a junction to a very short path, I can't make the tooling use that very short path...

Comment: What solution would you expect? It looks like you need to adjust your tooling so that it uses a different path.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, you're right, except that the tooling is non-trivial and unwrapping all the layers of the onion would take more time than I have. I have minutes or maybe hours, that would take weeks. Getting a Mac is more feasible, but looking at other opportunities first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com/android/tools/idea/npw/PathValidationResult.java` has the following code:

```
    if (SystemInfo.isWindows && projectLocation.length() > WINDOWS_PATH_LENGTH_LIMIT) {
      return error(PathValidationResult.Message.PATH_TOO_LONG, fieldName);
    }
```

Where `WINDOWS_PATH_LENGTH_LIMIT = 100;`

The solution is to adjust your tooling so that it uses project and Android SDK paths shorter than **100** characters or switch to Linux/macOS.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder - that's a great find. I'm investigating how feasible it is for me to patch the blasted `.class` files...

Comment: @0xbe5077ed Android SDK may have some deep tree structure and even if you patch it, it may fail further in the code when the Android SDK tooling will try to access the paths which really exceed the OS limits.

Comment: Note that it's technically possible to run IntelliJ IDEA under WSL on Windows using some X Window Server, for instance `VcXsrv`. Or you can install a Linux in a VM using VirtualBox. This might be a faster/easier way to overcome this limitation without adjusting your tooling.

Comment: My plan to patch the `.class` files failed. I was able to find the file in a JAR within the IDEA plugins directory, but when I increased the 100-character limit using a `.class` editor, it fixed the immediate issue and just caused more flakiness. I think you're right there must be some deeply nested tree issue. In any case, sadly for the time being I'm dumping the corporate tooling to get my POC done. So "Don't use Windows" is currently the best answer :(